# How to import postgresql data into sqlite3 (django specific)

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite

I would like to know how I can copy data from my production server (django+postresql) to my local dev servers (win7+sqlite3 + ubuntu+sqlite3).

My data is dumped in json format.

Answer (score 1):

Use `manage.py`'s `loaddata` predicate to load the dumped data.

Comment: That would be a problem with your data.

Answer (score 1):

After first *syncdb* Django inserts some initial data to some tables (for eg. content_types, superuser). Remove your sqlite3 database, and run `./manage.py syncdb --noinput`. If there's any data in tables, truncate them before running *loaddata*.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I am still getting the same [error](http://pastebin.com/5yKFe6nu).

1. deleted the db 2. manage.py syncdb --noinput 3. django-admin.py loaddata datadump.json --settings=settings

Comment: Have you truncated django_* tables?